# WCF with basicHttpBinding, encryption, signing and usernameToken over HTTP

Tags: c#, wcf-client, basichttpbinding, usernametoken

I'm trying to configure WCF client to generate proper request.
In that request I need security header with usernameToken. 
Also, I need to encrypt and sign request.
All this is communicated via plain HTTP.

So far, I have managed to make client sign and encrypt message.
Now I need to somehow incorporate usernameToken into this security header.

How can I do this?

I'm using basicHttpBinding, with security mode set to "Message" and clientCredentialType = "Certificate" for message.

I stumbled upon clearUsernameToken binding library but I see no way of incorporating all of this (usernameToken, sign and encrypt) into one client, and all that over HTTP.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this with WSE 3.0.

Now in my SOAP request I have UsernameToken, BinarySecurityToken, digital signature and encryption. Of course, I had to do some custom WSE filters, but it wasn't that hard.

For me it's strange that this was easier to achieve in older framework like WSE, then by using WCF.